# How to convert sqlite to sqlite3

Tags: sqlite, terminal

how to convert sqlite data base to sqlite3?
Can someone help me please 
I use windows and Mac 
hello everybody
how to convert sqlite data base to sqlite3?
Can someone help me please 
I use windows and Mac

Comment: Have you looked at the docs at sqlite.org?

Comment: yes but no  solution .. I have an app using sqlite3 and I already have a sqlite database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQLiteStudio](https://sqlitestudio.pl) can do that for you. It handles all differences between SQLite 2 and SQLite 3 on the fly. Just add SQLite 2 database to SQLiteStudio, then right-click on the database and pick "Convert database type". Then pick output file to write new SQLite file into and confirm the dialog window. That's all.